# Buttons Events In Style In WPF

Tags: wpf, button, styles

I tried to make a style to a button 
with three event :
onmouseenter - onmouseleave - onclick

on these event upload a different image ... and I need this style to added onto multiple buttons .

but don't know how to do it in style .

note I need to put this code in Resource Dictionary and include it in all the application to added to all buttons .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override Button's ControlTemplate and use VisualStates to handle different states:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverImage"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground"  Margin="0" >
                            <Image x:Name="NormalImage" Source="Resources\Normal.png"/>
                            <Image x:Name="MouseOverImage" Source="Resources\MouseOver.png" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <Image x:Name="PressedImage" Source="Resources\Pressed.png" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I got this error . The object 'Border' already has a child and cannot add 'Image'. 'Border' can accept only one child.

Comment: You can add a Grid between Border and Images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="viewImage" Property="Source" Value="/Images/noImage.png" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="OnMouseEnter" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="viewImage" Property="Source" Value="/Images/noImage.png" />
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="OnMouseLeave" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="viewImage" Property="Source" Value="/Images/noImage.png" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Hope this helps you.